# "Mock the http client" vs "Mock the web service"

Tags: playframework, mocking, integration-testing

[This blurb](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTestingWebServiceClients) from the Play framework denounces mocking the http client but encourages mocking the web service. I'm failing to see the big advantage of this.

If we're using the WSClient, which is provided by the Play framework wouldn't mocking the http client (the WSClient) vs the web service essentially be the same thing? I understand that between the WSClient and the web service would be the construction of the HTTP payload, it traveling across network etc. But if we were mocking the web service I don't see any different unless we were explicitly testing network failure cases and the like.

Comment: To my understanding a web service in this context IS a HTTP client and you are right when you say that mocking a http client vs mocking a web service is the same thing. What I think the 'blurb' meant is that usually when people mock a HTTP client they only care for the basics, e.g. was the connection established and 'something' received. They want to encourage you to use this WSClient to do more thorough testing.